# NCHW input matrix to Dm conversion logic for convolution in cuDNN

Tags: convolution, linear-algebra, cuda

I have been trying to understand the convolution lowering operation shown in the [cuDNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0759.pdf). I was able to understand most of it by reading through and mapping various parameters to the image below. However, I am unable to understand how the original input data (NCHW) was converted into the Dm matrix shown in red.

The ordering of the elements of the Dm matrix does not make sense. Can someone please explain this?

[image]

Comment: Each column in the Dm matrix contains the values from a 2x2 square (i.e. the filter size) from the original D matrix, which is unravel to go from 2x2 to 4x1. The 2x2 square starts at the top left (values 0 to 4) and then moves over the rest of the D matrix from left to right, top to bottom. This then gives 4 arrays of length 4, which are then concatenated columnwise to get to the Dm matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I am still having some trouble understanding why the elements of the Dm matrix are arranged in some order that is unexplained.

Assume, K =1, C = 1, with this we would have the following products:
Column 1: 
F0 * D4,
F1 * D3,
F2 * D1,
F3 * D0

Column 2:
F0 * D5,
F1 * D4,
F2 * D2,
F3 * D1

Column 3:
F0 * D7,
F1 * D6,
F2 * D4,
F3 * D3

Column 4:
F0 * D8,
F1 * D7,
F2 * D5,
F3 * D4

But in the above list of products (Fm x Dm), there is no F0 * D0 which is the first product you would expect.